# Problem with finding the degree between two clock hands question (Python)

Tags: python

Hi I seem to have a problem with my answer in returning the smallest angle between the big hand and small hand of a clock. The code I have is written below

```
def time_question(n):
    
    h = int(n[:2])
    m = int(n[2:])

    
    hours = (360/12)*h+((m/60)*(360/60))
    minutes = (360/60)*m
    
    diff = abs(hours-minutes)
    
    print(min(diff,360-diff)) time_question('1201')
```

Jupyter Notebook and Pycharm returns the value (5.8999999997)

while repl.it returns (5.5). I had an interview with this question and the interviewer had 5.5 as an answer as well. I was just wondering why my results are different? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you’re using the same version of Python (Python 3) for all of them, for one.

Comment: When I run this code on repl.it, I also get 5.899999999999977. Did you paste this exact code into repl.it?

Comment: Oh alright, I checked all and it seems that Repl is the only one showing 5.5 as the value, sublime, atom, pycharm and jupyter all show the same answer. Thank you!

Comment: @betaveros I checked it yeah hours is wrong it should be "(360/12)*h+(m/60)*(360/12) sorry my bad